# cordova is not defined - cordova.js has already been loaded :: Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

During the app running, this is what I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
ionic-core.js:466 Ionic Core: init
ionic-core.js:145 Ionic Core: searching for cordova.js
ionic-core.js:149 Ionic Core: cordova.js has already been loaded
```

Now this is making me confused but I assume that Ionic is trying to load cordova before it is defined. However, this prevents me from using other services that rely on this condition, so my question is, is there a way to load cordova async or what else might be my problem?

index.html

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>
<script src="lib/facebook-connect-plugin/index.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/utils.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-cordova` uses cordova so it must be loaded later:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to help :( still the same error I am running the app on an android device and debugging remotely via google chrome

Comment: @LubosMenus try to load cordova before any other script loads

Comment: Seems to be moving me closer to my goal! However, new errors arised..
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
ionic-core.js:466 Ionic Core: init
ionic-core.js:145 Ionic Core: searching for cordova.js
ionic-core.js:149 Ionic Core: cordova.js has already been loaded
plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173 No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.(anonymous function) @ plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173
app.js:209 Uncaught ReferenceError: $state is not defined

Comment: @LubosMenus dependency problems again, I don't know weather ionic uses requirejs, but some file is missing or sequence is wrong again

Answer (score 1):

cordova's plugin is designed for native plaform. So running ionic in a browser will fail all the plugins. That's the story.

Comment: Look into your platform/ios or android，you will see cordova do lots of jobs there. so without these jobs, how could your plugins work?